# Need help optimizing query, EXPLAIN says "using temporary, using filesort"

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a relatively simple game.  I need help I think this query isn't optimized correctly.

I have a standard `users` table.  There is an `expansions` table, which holds general information about the expansions in the game.  Each time a user beats a level in an expansion, a row is added to `playlog` that says their final score (so at first, there are 0 rows in the playlog table for them for the expansion).

```
EXPLAIN SELECT users.username, expansions.title, expansions.description, 
COUNT( playlog.id ) as  levels_beaten
FROM users
INNER JOIN expansions
LEFT JOIN playlog ON users.id = playlog.user_id
AND expansions.id = playlog.expansions_id
WHERE users.id = 10
GROUP BY expansions.id
ORDER BY expansions.order_hint DESC
```

[image: explained query]

[image: example select]

I have the following indexes:

**users** `id - primary, username - unique`

**expansions** `id - primary, order_hint - index`

**playlog** `expansions_id - foreign, user_id - foreign`

I took a database class awhile back and I remember the using temporary and filesorts was supposed to be bad but I don't really remember how to rectify it or if it's okay in this instance (ALSO if I don't select the username, it says "Using Index" in the first row of Explain as well)

Comment: `INNER JOIN expansions` join _on what_ ?

Comment: @wildplasser: I added an ON for that, I think it made it worse though: http://i.imgur.com/eNobnhd.jpg

Comment: I don't see it. Please post the **real** code. downvoting ...

Comment: You mean that mysql actually _accepts_ this query (without ON) ?

Comment: I have a picture of the output of it there.  It is appropriately the "view" (figuratively) that I am trying to make

Comment: Sorry, I cannot read pictures.

Comment: Wait a second: you post incomplete _non-executing_ code, I ask you for a fixup, you point me to a silly non-relevant graphic (which I cannot read) and you are calling me a `faggot troll`. I feel your pain. really.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, joins without on clause are accepted, it's a cross join.

Comment: So `INNER join` without `ON` is simalar to `,` ? I think I am going to put mysql into my deny list, now. @y2k: sorry, a different toolset creates a different mindset, apparently.

Comment: @wildplasser it's a cartesian product: every possible combination of records from both sides

Answer (score 0):

Your query looked mostly accurate, but the trail of comments was taking a negative spin.  I've rewritten the query to more explicitly show the relationship of the tables and join criteria.  You had left vs inner joins.  It appears from your description that the "Expansions" table is like a master list of expansions that ARE AVAILABLE in the game (like a lookup table).  The ONLY way a record gets into the PLAYLOG is IF someone completes a given expansion.  That said, start with the user to their playlog history.  If no records, you are done anyhow.  If there IS a playlog, then join to the expansions to get the descriptions.  No need to get expansion descriptions if nobody completed any such levels.

```
SELECT 
      users.username, 
      expansions.title, 
      expansions.description, 
      COUNT( * ) as  levels_beaten
   FROM 
      users
         JOIN playlog 
            ON users.id = playlog.user_id
            JOIN expansions
               ON playlog.expansions_id = expansions.id
   WHERE 
      users.id = 10
   GROUP BY 
      expansions.id
   ORDER BY 
      expansions.order_hint DESC
```

If the query still appears to cause an issue, I would then suggest adding the keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" such as

SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN  ...rest of query.

STRAIGHT_JOIN tells the engine to query in the order I've said and not let it interpret a possibly less efficient query path.